# chrome.cookies.onChanged in chrome extension not showing httpOnly cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When creating a new Chrome extension I would like to send a notification to the user whenever a new cookie is created/updated however it seems that when using https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#event-onChanged
no httpOnly cookies are returned.

```
browser.cookies.onChanged.addListener(function(changeInfo) {
  console.log('Cookie changed: ' +
              '\n * Cookie: ' + JSON.stringify(changeInfo.cookie) +
              '\n * Cause: ' + changeInfo.cause +
              '\n * Removed: ' + changeInfo.removed);
});
```

I figured there was something wrong with my permissions but when using

```
chrome.cookies.getAll({}, callback)
```

all the cookies are extracted perfectly fine using this method however I am only interested in changes to the cookies (notably, added cookies) so this is not really what I need.

I have made sure to include `"cookies"` in the manifest.json permissions.

The code itself is running on the background.js script

in background.js

```js
chrome.cookies.onChanged.addListener(function(changeInfo) {
  alert(JSON.stringify(changeInfo.cookie))
});
```

manifest.json

```
 "permissions": [
  "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "cookies"
  ],

 "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
 }
```

When refreshing/opening a new page after clearing all cookies there should be an alert popup with the cookie details, I would expect there to be all the new cookies for that page however I am only being displayed cookies with the httpOnly flag set to false. I verified this by also outputting it to the console and the same problem appeared.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I'm having the same problem